Ubuntu Server Wifi Issues
I am trying to set up an 24.04 LTS Ubuntu server. In the installation GUI, I was able connect to my WiFi. I have added my WiFi information to /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml file, and added the 99-disable-network-config.yaml file. When I try to run ping command half the time it doesn’t work and only after using the netplan apply command. Even if the ping command works to verify connection, I cannot run sudo apt-get update. The only ping that works always is the gateway address so I know it is reaching the router at least.
Any ideas?
I tried manually setting name servers dhcp on and off, used gpt to try and troubleshoot. Used the GUI, reset router CLI commands I ran

Please edit the question and add the contents of the 2 yaml files.

Doesn't help with the question but why are you using WiFi for server network connectivity? It won't be as reliable as a cabled connection. Does the WiFi connection work well with other operating systems (i.e. could it be a hardware/antenna issue)?
